# Butterfly Labs Little Single No Devices Found

Tags: butterfly-labs

When I am trying to mine with my new butterfly labs little single BFGminer says that it cannot detect any devices. I try and add devices, and it doesn't work. I know that it is getting power, because my OS will recognize that the miner has been plugged into the computer. I have tried now on both linux and windows with no luck getting it to recognize it. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you compile it with support for BFL miners? They are obsolete at this point so there's a very good chance they aren't enabled by default, if so the section "How do I get my BFL/Icarus/Lancelot/Cairnsmore device to auto-recognise?" in the [bfgminer readme](https://github.com/luke-jr/bfgminer) might be educational.

Comment: OK, I looked at the readme and saw that I need to install the driver. However, it didn't list the command for getting the BFL little single driver. I assume that it is the same, I just need the details of the command.